# Computing the Gauss curvature of the hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let $S = \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 \ | \ z = x^2 - y^2\}$ be the hyperbolic paraboloid. Our aim is to compute the Gauss curvature at the origin. I thought I knew how to do this, but I keep getting this wrong. Any hints towards the right direction will be the most appreciated.

I proceeded as follows:

We know that the hyperbolic paraboloid is the graphic of a function $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$, hence orientable with unit normal field
$$
N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f|^2}}(-f_x, -f_y, 1)
$$
where the subindex denotes partial differentiation. Then, for our function, 
$$
N(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4(x^2 + y^2)}}(-2x, 2y, 1).
$$
I then tried to compute the jacobian matrix of N at the point $(x, y, z)$, which gives us $(dN)_{(x, y, z)}$. At the origin, we have 
$$
(dN)_{(0, 0, 0)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
what gives zero Gauss curvature since the determinant of this matrix is zero. However, I was supposed to get a negative value. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I chacked my computations with WolframAlpha.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Confer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2622766/finding-the-eigenvalues-of-differential-normal-mapping-of-the-hyperbolic-parabol

Comment: $N$ should be a function of $x$ and $y$ only.

Comment: Thank you very much. The question you linked indeed solves the question, but it follows a completely different way of thought. I checked my book, and he only speaks about those formulas for the curvatures much later. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: if you have $z = f(x,y)$ and a point, say the origin, is a critical point of $f,$ the Gauss curvature is just the determinant of the ordinary Hessian matrix, the mean curvature is just the trace (tmes a constant, some people divide by $2,$ also usage varies as far as positive or negative mean curvature)  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Michigan_1991.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I prove your assetion? I couldn't find the proof in your paper.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin . A brief recipe is: since $||N||=1$ then $N_x,N_y$ are perpendicular to the tangent base, so $$N_x=P\partial_x+Q\partial_y$$ and $$N_y=R\partial_x+S\partial_y$$ for some scalars, then $K_{\rm Gauss}=PS-QR$.